# How to use regex contains " with Pattern.compile

Tags: java, regex

i have this regex :

```
url\(\s*(['"]?+)(.*?)\1\s*\)
```

Which retrieves all url from css file .

I use this code , However i get an error :

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("url\(\s*(['\"]?+)(.*?)\1\s*\)");
      Matcher m = p.matcher(cssText);
      while (m.find()) {
          println m.group()
        }
```

As you can note that i add `\` to esacpe `"` . But in vain

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `\\` instead of `\` in Java regex:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile( "url\\(\\s*(['\"]?+)(.*?)\\1\\s*\\)" );
```

- 1st `\` is for escaping from String object
- 2nd `\` is for escaping from underlying regex engine